# php image title output display

Tags: javascript

I have a image where title value is as folowing:

image title:

```
title="sample"
```

Example Code :

```
<img src="images/bar_offpeak.jpg" class="usagegraphimage" id="ctl00_ctl00_contentDefault_contentControlPanel_totalusage" width="19" height="<?php echo "$bar" ?>%" title="<?php echo "$dailyuse" ?>GB" value="<?php echo "$dailyuse" ?>" alt="Click to view usage"/>
```

I want to have a text below the image showing the images "title" once you click on the image.

Comment: What do you mean by 'image value' and 'name value'?

Comment: You have tried almost the exact question before and it was marked down because it made no sense. There is no point keeping on with this. You need to change what you are saying because no one understands this.

Comment: The img tag does not have a value attribute.

Comment: sorry my mistake , i meant the "title"

Comment: `name` is also not a valid attribute for an `<img>` element: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element

Comment: ok still....how do I show the images "title" once you click on the image.
I want it to show below the image

Comment: possible duplicate of [php image name output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530766/php-image-name-output)

Comment: @user2080473 This would be done via JavaScript. This has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. JavaScript is **client side**. PHP is **server side**. Click events are **client events** and therefore use JavaScript not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to:

> > show the images "title" once you click on the image

This can be achieved with javascipt (using jquery in this example) if that helps:

```
<div id="imgArea">
    <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo4w.png" title="The Image Title" id="imgToClick" />
    <div id="imgTitle"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#imgArea').delegate('#imgToClick','click',function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#imgTitle').html(title);
});
</script>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rLTac/